# NPM gives error when using Laravel Mix node module

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-8, laravel-mix

Laravel Mix has been installed the following way.

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

But when running `npm run production` (happens with `npm run dev` too), I get the following error. I have deleted my node modules folder again and again and tried to install the laravel mix command by using the `npm install laravel-mix --save` command as well, same results, however.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the contents of your package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing process as a dev dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev process
```